# How to compare two images and highlight the difference in new image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a flutter developer. My need is to compare two images and highlight the difference (between two images) in a new image in flutter?

Two images **First image** and **Second image**.

My requirement is to compare those images and highlight the difference region in another image **Difference image**. I am trying to achieve screenshot based UI testing in flutter and need to fail the test cases if there is any differences between two images.

Please find the below screenshots for reference.

[image]

Is there any package in flutter/dart to achieve the same output?

Thanks and regards,

Ashwin

Answer (score 8):

A few months ago I read your question, and today I've just uploaded a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/diff_image) that do what you want.

```dart
import 'package:diff_image/diff_image.dart';

final FIRST_IMAGE = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nicolashahn/diffimg/master/images/mario-circle-cs.png';
final SECOND_IMAGE = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nicolashahn/diffimg/master/images/mario-circle-node.png';

num getDiff() async{
  try{
      var diff = await DiffImage.compareFromUrl(
            FIRST_IMAGE,
            SECOND_IMAGE,
            saveDiff:True
      );
      print('The difference between images is: $diff %');
      return diff;
  } catch(e){
      print(e);
  }
}

main() {
  getDiff();
}
```

With two images as input, it returns the difference ratio between them, and exactly as you want, save the "diff image" as png.

I guess it can solve your problem but if you need something more specific, feel free to ask me the feature you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for working on this! Have you by any chance worked on a null safe version of this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the **Golden File Test**:

- [flutter/Writing a golden file test for package:flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Writing-a-golden-file-test-for-package:flutter)
- [medium/Do you see the difference? — Flutter Snapshot test](https://medium.com/flutter-community/do-you-see-the-difference-flutter-golden-files-a1d431ed8a69)
- [medium/Flutter: Golden tests — compare Widgets with Snapshots](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-golden-tests-compare-widgets-with-snapshots-27f83f266cea)

Basically, you create your *golden* widget and make an image snapshot of it.

Then during the test, you check to see if the app is displaying the exact same thing:

```
await expectLater(
    find.byType(RepaintBoundary),
    matchesGoldenFile('golden-file.png'),
  );
```

So while it's not exactly your requirements, `image==image?`, it is at least `image==live app display?`

And for side-curiosities, Facebook also created something similar for native Android: http://facebook.github.io/screenshot-tests-for-android/

Answer (score 1):

My team and I created the [image_compare](https://pub.dev/packages/image_compare) package to calculate differences between two images. There is a variety of algorithms to achieve this task such as percentage difference from overlaying images, euclid. color distance, RGB histogram comparison, and hashing comparison such as perceptual hash.

Here's quick example:

```
import 'package:image_compare/image_compare.dart';

// ...

Future<double> compare() async {
  var a = File('../images/tiger.jpg');
  var b = Uri.parse('https://fujifilm-x.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/x-t30_sample- images03.jpg');

  return compareImages(src1: a, src2: b);
}

// ...
```

Comment: im using your library and passing 2 images says that "flutter: Unsupported operation: The source, Image, passed in is unsupported" which is funny since it says they are Image class any idea?

Comment: That's a common package conflict since there are multiple image classes in dart from various libraries. Please make sure to use this [image class](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/Image-class.html). If you have multiple imports for the image classes (widget, dart:ui, or image library) please consider using named imports `import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;` and comparing the images with `compareImages(src1: img.src1, src2: img.src2)`

Comment: I have used the named imports now, but seems that there is no way to transform a Image from another package that im using is a shame :/, I got this far but gets me the error that the image data.length is not the same as width*height

Comment: That error is thrown when there is a mismatch between the image data stored and the dimensions. This generally occurs when an unsupported set of conversions are performed.

My suggestion would be to convert the image into bytes and use that as the source for the images. Otherwise, you can save locally and then use our support for the File class to load the images in. 

Besides that, if you'd like help with the conversions, please send the code you used to convert from the other image class, specifying the library it's from.

Comment: yeah That worked thanks! I used rgba as my format on my original image, the other package was formating the bytes as "png" and saw that on the possible options to export was this "rawRgba" which is one of the formats on the fromBytes() function and that did the trick

Comment: No problem! I recommend using [decodeImage(List<int> bytes)](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/Decoder/decodeImage.html) from the image library to create an image object rather than `Image.fromBytes(int width, int height, List<int> bytes)` since the latter requires you to specify the correct dimensions for the byte array while the former does it automatically for you.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the same code works with both images with white backgrounds but with transparent backgrounds always return 84.766 % all the time?

Comment: Version 1.1.2 introduces the capability to handle transparency, please use that version if you need to account for the alpha channel.